# Copy paste a given line number from one xml file to another xml file

Tags: xml, shell

How do i copy a given series of line numbers from one xml file to another xml file.

Ex - File1

```
<home>
<heading>
 hello
</heading>
<heading2>
world
</heading2>
.........
.........
</home>
```

File 2

```
<home>
<heading>
 this is a heading
</heading>
<heading2>
 this is a heading
</heading2>
.........
.........
</home>
```

o/p

```
<home>
<heading>
 hello
</heading>
<heading2>
world
</heading2>
.........
.........
</home>
```

Lets say i have given input as line no 3 and line no 6 below would be my output. I need to change only the given particular lines.
My file is very huge, just given a sample Any suggestions?

Comment: so your output is identical to File 1?

Comment: not exactly.. only few lines will be changing when we compare file 1 and file 2. lets says the first 10-20 lines will be changing when we compare file1 and file 2

Comment: not all the lines are same, There are some unique lines in the xml

Comment: It's a very odd requirement, because "lines" in XML are not structural units, and copying lines of text (as distinct from complete elements) from one XML document into another will in general produce something that isn't XML.

Comment: I agree,since my xml is not in same structure completely.
Is there any way where i can change the value using the tag's

Answer (score 0):

to see what you are working with, and maybe give a better view of your problem:

```
   $ pr -tn file1   >   file1.prt
   $ ... file2      >   file2.prt
```